# How do I notify someone about a missing argument?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm developing a discord bot using Discord py, and one of the commands is to take someone's profile pic. I made this ok, but I am having some problems.
Basically I want to warn the user that he needs to mention the guy he wants the pic, the argument.

The code itself is working perfectly, but i want to tell then that is necessary mention.

````
async def avatar(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  show_avatar = discord.Embed(
    title = f'Aqui está a foto dele, senhor {ctx.author}',
    color = 2602879
  )
  show_avatar.set_image(url='{}'.format(member.avatar_url))
  await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}', embed=show_avatar)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an errorhandler to let them know. Here is a simple format with a bit of explanation:

```py
@avatar.error # Decorator to specify this is the handler for this command only
async def avatar_handler(ctx, error): # Context and error required
    if isinstance(error, discord.BadArgument): # Check if the exception is what you want to handler
        await ctx.send(f"**Error:**\n{str(error)}") # Customize error however you want. This will just show the error
```

`discord.BadArgument` is one of the many exceptions you can handle in a handler. This one, in particular, will be raised if there is a parsing or conversion error.

See [`discord.BadArgument`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.BadArgument) and the [list of exceptions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#exceptions) and the [tutorial on handlers](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling)